# In-App Purchase fails after release

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iOS application with In-App Purchase (IAP). I tested the IAP (in the sandbox environment) and it's working fine.

However, once we released the app we started facing an issue -  users buy subscription but the content is still restricted.

My app has auto-renewal subscriptions. I check receipt by sending it to buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. I receive the receipt

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL].
```

Restore purchase via `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` doesn’t work as well.

Can I test it in another environment except for sandbox in order to understand what cases the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For in-app testing, better to invite users to test your app via [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) before you release your app on the App Store.

Comment: This is not an answer... It can be comment but doesn't provide answer....

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that your in-app purchases have not been set up correctly. Check them very, very carefully. Incorrectly set up in-app purchases can work during development, even during app review, and fail on a life build.